# The value in context can not transmitted in different package？

Tags: go

Today I try to program with context,code as follow:

```
package main

func main(){
  ctx := context.Background()
  ctx = context.WithValue(ctx,"appid","test111")
  b.dosomething()
}


package b

func dosomething(ctx context.Context){
    fmt.Println(ctx.Value("appid").(string))
}
```

Then my program has crashed.I think it's due to that these ctx is in different package

Comment: This code doesn't seem to compile due to a missing argument.

Comment: Why were trying to use contexts, without learning basics? `dosomething(...)` should be `DoSomething(...)`, pass your `ctx` as argument `b.DoSomething(ctx)`.

Comment: @bereal `dosomething` is also unexported

Comment: Where are you importing the context package, and the fmt package, and the b package.

Comment: @pengliam you simplified your program to a degree when it does not demonstrate the original problem but makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use context only in a lifetime of a single task and pass the same context through functions.
Also you should understand where to use context and where just to pass arguments to functions.

Another suggestion is to use custom types for setting and getting values from context.

According to all above, you program should look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

type KeyMsg string

func main() {
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), KeyMsg("msg"), "hello")
    DoSomething(ctx)
}

// DoSomething accepts context value, retrieves message by KeyMsg and prints it.
func DoSomething(ctx context.Context) {
    msg, ok := ctx.Value(KeyMsg("msg")).(string)
    if !ok {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("got msg:", msg)
}
```

You can move function DoSomething into another package and just call it as packagename.DoSomething it will change nothing.

Comment: Well, except that moving `DoSomething` to another package would eliminate the ability to get the `"msg"` value back out, since the `keyMsg()` type is unexported.  If you're using named types for the key (though int constants with `iota` work just as well for that), they either have to be exported or your package has to provide exported getter and setter functions for the context values.